# C# how to have multiple keywords in mvc url structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Right now I create view named "About" and its url structure is for example **Home/About**
But how can I create url like this, with complex, multiple keywords? For example **Home/Hello-World-This-Is-My-Url** I cant create view with spaces and replace space with '-'. I need this only on Home controller, nowhere else.

Comment: How much do you know about routing?

Comment: I know some.. but site is very complex with lot of pages and structure, I dont want to mess it up else where. I need this only on Home controller

Comment: Put this at the top of your route definitions `routes.MapRoute(null, "Home/Hello-World-This-Is-My-Url", new { controller = "Home", action = "WhateverYouWantItToBe" });`

Comment: I have to do this individual, each time i add page with keywords?

Comment: How else would it know which action to invoke?

Comment: Yeah, makes sense, ok then! Thanks man.. i will try this